# Symfony2 mapping file not found

Tags: mongodb, file, symfony, annotations

I have a little form, with just a file field to upload a document. I'm using Symfony2.6 with mongodb annotation. I get a "No mapping found for field 'file'" exception.
My document class :

```
namespace My\Bundle\Document;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
* @MongoDB\Document
*/
class ImportFile
{
[...]
/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize = "5M", mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"})
 */
protected $file;
[...]
/**
 * @return $file
 */
public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}

/**
 * @param $file
 */
public function setFile($file)
{
    $this->file = $file;
}
```

(the namespace is correct, i changed it for the post)

Here is my controller with my form builder :

```
 $importFile = new ImportFile();
 $form = $this->createFormBuilder($importFile)
         ->add('file')
         ->getForm();
```

The file field should be automatically detected (as it mentioned here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) but it doesn't work. If i add:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($importFile)
         ->add('file','file')
         ->getForm();
```

it works, but i should'nt have to add the file type as it should be automatically detected. what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your annotation. You added just an assert but no field definition:

```
/**
 * @Field(type="file")
 * @Assert\File(maxSize = "5M", mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"})
 */
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I don't want this field to be mapped in the database, i just need it for the upload process. If i add the annotation field(file), it will store my image into the mongodb dataGridFS, what i don't want. Also considering this doc  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html, it seems no need to add any more annotation.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention here:

> I don't want this field to be mapped in the database

You should use mapped property at form field definition:

```
 mapped => false
```

So, this should resolved your problem ( but remeber that after submit, value from file property will not be mapped with your odm Document ):

```
 $form = $this->createFormBuilder($importFile)
            ->add('file', 'file', array(
                'mapped' => false
            ))
            ->getForm();
```

More here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#mapped